# Sharing a link causing unauthorised access error

Tags: permissions, hyperlink

I have created a page and it is shared with everyone.

When I send a user a link to that `http://sharepoint.ac.uk/DispForm.aspx?ID=1`, the user get an error saying they are not authorised to view the page. But the user can view the contents of this page if they click on the link on the dashboard.

Unsure what the problem is

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Permission issue was due to the user clicking on the link that opened in a non IE browser.